# Caching Image files between python(memcache) and php(apache)

Tags: php, python, apache, memcached

I am running python and apache on server side and I need to pass an image generated in Python to a php page.

I have tried to use memcache, converting the image to a string before sending to the server, but I can't open it in php this string as Image e show on screen....

Can you help me?

Python:

```
shared = memcache.Client([('127.0.0.1:11211')])
imagefile= pygame.image.load(image.png)
data = pygame.image.tostring(imagefile, "RGBA", True)
shared.set('SharedImage',data)
```

php:

```
<?php
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$src = $mem->get('SharedImage');
$ImageRead=imagecreatefromstring ( string $src);
echo $ImageRead;
?>
```

Comment: post some php and python code.

Comment: code posted.   =)